# How can I make odds ratio and 95% CI for chi-square test in gtsummary with my own function?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to create the table shown here with gtsummary, can you please let me know?

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZxY7.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

You can add the odds ratio via a custom function passed to `add_difference()`. Instructions on how to construct a custom function are here https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tests.html#custom-functions-1.

I've written an example below. But please take careful note of how `fisher.test()` constructs the odds ratio from the 2x2 table. You may need to switch the order of the variables in `table()` or even reverse the order of your variable levels to get the odds ratio you need.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.0'

# function to calculate OR from 2x2 table
or_fun <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  table(data[[by]], data[[variable]]) %>%
    fisher.test() %>%
    broom::tidy()
}
# testing function
or_fun(trial, "trt", "response")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   estimate p.value conf.low conf.high method                         alternative
#>      <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                          <chr>      
#> 1     1.21   0.540    0.633      2.34 Fisher's Exact Test for Count… two.sided

# add OR to a `tbl_summary()`
tbl <-
  trial %>%
  select(response, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no", statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)") %>%
  add_difference(test = response ~ or_fun, estimate_fun = response ~ style_ratio) %>%
  modify_header(estimate ~ "**Odds Ratio**")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That's really helpful (as your whole package is!). Is it possible to adapt this code to calculate ORs for more than one characteristic?

Comment: Just change `add_difference(test = response ~ or_fun)` to `add_difference(test = everything() ~ or_fun)` or list all the variables you want this to apply to instead of everything